# Remote host Mysql access

Tags: mysql, web, hosting, remote-access

Is it a fact that most host providers that provide mysql as a part of other services such as website hosting, limit access to mysql by only phpmyadmin or within the hosted application is self ?

this seems obvious for me where when i for example try to connect from my localhost by mysql workbench to remote mysql of some of the host providers out there i get either access denied even if i allowed privileges for anyone to access this mysql host , or i get could not connect message for some reason.

On the other hand when a host provider provides only mysql as the main service not a part of other services i could access my database from any where normally.

So i wanted to know if what i said was true.

Take an example by registering to for example any free php hosting websites out there that include mysql as a part of the services , you will find that you can't access your mysql data from mysql workbench in your local machine for example.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Most hosting providers limit access to IP addresses local to their network, or even the same server the web site runs on. It's good security, given that there have been mySQL security breaches in the past [(example)](http://www.darkreading.com/application-security/database-security/expect-a-surge-in-breaches-following-mysql-vulnerability/d/d-id/1137866?). (Not entirely sure this is a good, on-topic question for SO though...)